# How to make sum of expression results

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

I have one rdlc report in which last column value is sum of all row values
And last row will be sum of values in colums.And last cell of last column will be total of Totals obtained rowwise.
I am unable to calculate sum value of last cell in last row and column .Because wizard only shows me the dataset's column values and not expression result.
In short i want to cunsume expression result in summation.How to achieve this?what will be the expression

Answer (score 0):

[Redesigning a Customer - Order Summary Report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd338989.aspx)